# matlab - Sort cells array according mode

Tags: matlab

How can I sort a matrix using a specific column, with changing direction?
I've tried this, but don't work.

```
data:
    A1  5  P19
    A2  7  P45
    A3  8  P7

[Y,I] = sort(data(:,3), 'descend');
B = data(Y,3);
```

I need to get:

```
In Ascending
    A3  8  P7
    A1  5  P19
    A2  7  P45

In descending:
        A2  7  P45
        A1  5  P19
        A3  8  P7
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide your code (including input data) in a way it could be copied to reproduce your problem. I assume data a cell? Not sure about this. What error message do you get?

Comment: Your problem is that 'P19' comes before 'P7' because of the dictionary sorting. You need to have 'P07' to be able to sort as you   intend to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sort in *alphabetical* order (not what you want) according to column 3:

```
[Y,I] = sort(data(:,3)); %// I gives the indices of sorted rows 
B_asc = data(I,:); %// ascending
B_des = data(I(end:-1:1),:); %// descending
```

To sort in *numerical* order (which seems to be what you want) according to column 3 without the "P":

```
aux = strvcat(data(:,3)); %// put column 3 into matrix form, with trailing spaces
[Y,I] = sort(str2num((aux(:,2:end)))); %// convert to number and sort
B_asc = data(I,:); %// ascending
B_des = data(I(end:-1:1),:); %// descending
```

Comment: Tanks. I get an error on define mode sort. As if mode cannot be apply to cells array. I'll give you exact message.

Comment: @TimeIsNear You're right, mode is not supported with cells. See updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your data is a cell matrix:

```
A = {'A1'  5  'P19'; 'A2'  7  'P45'; 'A3'  8  'P7'};
temp = char(A(:,3));
temp = str2num(temp(:,2:end));  %get rid of the P
```

---

```
[~,idx1] = sort(temp,'ascend')
A(idx1,:)
```

will give you:

```
'A3'    [8]    'P7' 
'A1'    [5]    'P19'
'A2'    [7]    'P45'
```

and

```
[~,idx2] = sort(temp,'descend')
A(idx2,:)
```

will give you:

```
'A2'    [7]    'P45'
'A1'    [5]    'P19'
'A3'    [8]    'P7'
```

---

If your data could be changed to:

```
A = {'A1'  5  'P19'; 'A2'  7  'P45'; 'A3'  8  'P07'};
```

it would make everything easier, as everybody initially thought here:

```
B = sortrows(A,3);
C = flipud(B);

B = 

    'A3'    [8]    'P07'
    'A1'    [5]    'P19'
    'A2'    [7]    'P45'


C = 

    'A2'    [7]    'P45'
    'A1'    [5]    'P19'
    'A3'    [8]    'P07'
```

Comment: Thanks.I 've more than 6000 rows to sort  I'll see which method take less time.